# How do I get one word out of a URL?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd love to know how to get the word "author" from a url as in

```
www.example.com/?author=seth-godin
```

I'm using wordpress - so I can always know that the URL will look exactly like that. I've used Regex to get everything after the "/" but that's too much. Here's that code.

```
preg_match("/[^\/]+$/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
$author = $matches[0]; // test
```

Any help?

Comment: Note: I need the actual word "author" regardless of what the value is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$key = array_keys($_GET);
$key = $key[0];
```

Comment: That's exactly right - thanks !Will accept answer when timer runs out :)

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` should be able to get the 'author=seth-godin' part, then just explode at & (if multiple parameters), or at = and use the first value i.e. `explode('=',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. zero index of that array = author. (similar to below)

array_keys($_GET) will return array(0=>'author');

Comment: XD, you're right haha. I only mentioned that because he was regexing in the first place. Not exactly sure what he wanted to use it for.